# Sublime Text 3 - Search case-sensitive toggle shortcut not working

Tags: toggle, sublimetext3, case-sensitive

The shortcut for toggling case-sensitivity for searches is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but this shortcut does not appear to work. The shortcut to toggle “RegEx” and “Whole word” searching work as expected, but for some reason I cannot get the toggle to work for case-sensitivity.

Mac OS X 10.11.4 - Sublime Text 3

Steps to reproduce:

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the "Find in Files" prompt at the bottom of the window
2. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to toggle case sensitivity -- nothing happens

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce the problem, so you should probably rule out any conflicting keyboard shortcuts. The [FindKeyConflicts](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts) helps identifying these kinds of conflicts.

If the problem persists, check if any other software uses the same shortcut globally.

Comment: The FindKeyConflicts plugin is great, but I wasn't able to find any key conflicts for the shortcut I specified. I'll look into posting in the Sublime Text forum. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Cmd+Alt+C to toggle case sensitivity works only while you are in the search dialog.

In other words, you need to hit Cmd+F to get to the search dialog and then hit Cmd+Alt+C to toggle case sensitivity.